# Get specific value in in one of the values of .CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I just want to ask something about getting values from CSV file.

I have a CSV file and I can get a value from it. But now I would like to get a specific value inside that value.

For example.

I have "name", "address and postal code", "phone" inside the .CSV file. I can get the value from the address and postal code. But now I only want the value of the postal code. How can I separate the address from the postal code if they're in one cell using php?

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSV. This has to do only to do with splitting an address from the postal code in a string. Maybe post the address string here, along with what you've already tried?

Comment: Sounds like this should be possible by a simple `explode` or by using some RegEx. But you need to post examples for us to say something more specific.

Comment: Okay thank you!!! I'll post it later! :) I'm currently at work and can't stop thinking about it.